# Unwanted extra space by \newcommand macro in MathJax

Tags: html, mathjax

When I use a LaTeX macro (\newcommand for example), it occupies space in the page. Here is an example code to demonstrate the issue I am facing.

URL: http://jsfiddle.net/Lkeus/

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>MathJax Example</title> 
<script 
type="text/javascript" 
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=default"> 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<p> 
\(\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\) 
\(\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\) 
\(\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\) 
Let \(x \in \N\). Then \(x^2\) is called a perfect square. 
</p> 
<p> 
Let \(x \in \N\). Then \(x^2\) is called a perfect square. 
</p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Here is the output in its own page: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Lkeus/show/

In the output, you can see that the first line begins after some space. This space comes from the use of macros there.  Firebug shows this code created by MathJax as the cause of the extra space:

```
<span class="math" id="MathJax-Span-1"> 
<span style="display: inline-block; position: relative; width: 0em; 
height: 0pt; font-size: 130%;"> 
<span style="position: absolute; top: -1em; left: 0em; clip: 
rect(0.856em, 1000em, 1.144em, -0.433em);"> 
<span class="mrow" id="MathJax-Span-2"></span> 
<span style="display: inline-block; width: 0pt; height: 1em;"></span> 
</span></span> 
<span style="border-left: 0em solid; display: inline-block; overflow: 
hidden; width: 0pt; height: 0em; vertical-align: 0em;"></span></span>
```

How can I get rid of this extra space?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I learnt a few solutions to this problem from the MathJax community.

It is possible to minimize the whitespace due to `\newcommand` by putting all the `\newcommand`s into a single `\(`...`\)`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/qQ9P9/

```
\(\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\)
```

It is possible to remove all the extra whitespace completely by defining the macros in the `<head>` section of the HTML. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/tVyJz/

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> 
MathJax.Hub.Config({ 
    TeX: { 
        Macros: { 
            N: "\\mathbb{N}", 
            R: "\\mathbb{R}", 
            Z: "\\mathbb{Z}" 
        } 
    } 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: FWIW, this has at least one drawback: You can't use `\def`-style delimited arguments this way, since all you can say is how many arguments your macro takes. So using `\def` in the text is more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

What I've been doing is putting the `newcommand` definitions in their own paragraph (or div) and then setting its `display` attribute to `none`:

```
<p style="display:none"> 
\(\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\) 
\(\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}\) 
\(\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}\) 
</p>
<p>
Let \(x \in \N\). Then \(x^2\) is called a perfect square. 
</p> 
<p> 
Let \(x \in \N\). Then \(x^2\) is called a perfect square. 
</p>
```